# Err 1054 - Unknown column 'column' in 'where clause' mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem in MySQL. Here is my code:

```
UPDATE ad_copy, (
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(" - ", ad_copy.title, stitle.ttitle) AS `p` 
    from ad_copy, stitle 
    where ad_copy.category = stitle.subcat 
    ORDER BY RAND()) `p` 
set `title` = `p` 
where ad_copy.category = stitle.subcat
```

I can not understand what the problem is. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what exactly you want to do? you query is not looking good to me.

Comment: sounds like you have a column name mismatch

Comment: your stitle.subcat is not in ad_copy, it is in sub query and not available for the main update query. i guess.

Comment: @Jaan I need to add a random value stitle.ttitle in ad_copy.title

Answer (score 0):

Try update with join , your custom column by subquery `(SELECT CONCAT_WS ..) as p` is not recognized

```
UPDATE 
ad_copy a
JOIN stitle  s ON (a.category = s.subcat)
SET a.`title` = CONCAT_WS( " - ",a.title,s.ttitle)
```

**EDIT**

```
UPDATE 
ad_copy a
JOIN stitle  s ON (a.category = s.subcat)
SET a.`title` = CONCAT_WS( " - ",a.title, (SELECT ttitle FROM stitle WHERE subcat =a.category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ))
```

Comment: @HunterNNm where you want to add random value ? in `title` ?